# PSCP from windows machine to EC2 instance using PSCP but files don't appear on the server

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-linux, pscp

I am sending a JAR file from my local system to an EC2 instance using PSCP. I am told the request was successful, although when I SSH into my EC2 instance and look for the file in the home directory, it is not there. Any idea why this is?

My request:

`pscp -v -P 22 -i C:\Users\seane\OneDrive\Desktop\Converted-MongoInstanceSSHKey.ppk C:/Users/seane/OneDrive/Desktop/CouncillorTest/target/CouncillorAppSB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar ec2-user@ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:~`

Response:

````
Connecting to x.xxx.xxx.xx port 22
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Release_0.74
Remote version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
Using SSH protocol version 2
No GSSAPI security context available
Doing ECDH key exchange with curve Curve25519 and hash SHA-256 (unaccelerated)
Server also has ecdsa-sha2-nistp256/ssh-rsa host keys, but we don't know any of them
Host key fingerprint is:
ssh-ed25519 255 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) outbound encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) outbound MAC algorithm
Initialised AES-256 SDCTR (AES-NI accelerated) inbound encryption
Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 (unaccelerated) inbound MAC algorithm
Reading key file "C:\Users\seane\OneDrive\Desktop\Converted-MongoInstanceSSHKey.ppk"
Using username "ec2-user".
Offered public key
Offer of public key accepted
Authenticating with public key "imported-openssh-key"
Sent public key signature
Access granted
Opening main session channel
Opened main channel
Started a shell/command
Using SFTP
Connected to ec2-x-xxx-xxx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Sending file CouncillorAppSB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar, size=23682691
CouncillorAppSB-1.0-SNAPS | 23127 kB | 2891.0 kB/s | ETA: 00:00:00 | 100%
Session sent command exit status 0
Main session channel closed
All channels closed```
````